# Open Source Ubuntu alternative to Quickbooks

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking to open my own business, and am trying to find an Ubuntu alternative to QuickBooks Professional.

I would love to find a SOLID business management system that allows estimating, invoicing, customer retention, full banking functions, and finally full accounting ability that makes tax time easy work for my CPA.

If anyone has any ideas, or are currently using an open-source program to run their business, I would be extremely interested in hearing from you, and your personal input on the software functionality.

Comment: Because training on accounting software can cost many of thousands of dollars and because it's mission critical another option would be to run that particular windows application under Wine or Virtual Box within Linux.

Comment: Consult your accountant as part of the process: Use the accounting software that your Accountant prefers, and that will cost you the least in tax preparation and other ongoing Accounting fees.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of Open books alternatives

- GNU Cash (Open Source)
- Odoo (Not open source, but free)
- Home bank (open source)
- Zipbook (Free) etc

Take a look here http://alternativeto.net/software/quickbooks/?license=free

---

Suggested by NonLinearFruit in a comment

- KMyMoney

Comment: thanks for that link @Anwar, I had no idea there were so many options out there including ERP solutions.

Comment: Thank you for all of your insight. It looks like I have homework to do !!!

Comment: The AskUbuntu way of giving thanks is giving the answer upvote or accept it (clicking the tick mark) as the correct one.

Comment: KMyMoney is another one

Comment: @NonlinearFruit edited to include the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the above. Then my bookkeeper said I must use Manager (www.manager.io). What an easy,free and very easy to learn program!

Download it and you will be pleasantly be surpised after a few days.

Comment: Looks like a good option!